# Inspecting visual tree in Flash Player / Chrome

Tags: flash, google-chrome

I am trying to copy some lines of text that are inside of this web app that I have to use for a math class.

The web app uses Flash Player, so I can't just select the text and copy it. I can't find anything in the Chrome Developer Tools. Is there some sort of program or chrome extension that you know of that will let me inspect the visual tree of the player so I can find this text and copy it to the clipboard?

I just want to be able to copy and paste math questions directly into a calculator to save time.

Thanks!

Comment: Not likely. SWF (Flash) is not HTML just a data format that also happens to display within a browser. If the text was not made selectable (using mouse hilight and `ctrl+C`) then you cant do much about it. Might even be done deliberate to stop rival sites copying. I hope a higher genius can show us a trick hopefully...

Comment: Yea I was thinking the same thing, there is a lot of debugging programs for flash, but I imagine that you need the source code to attach to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify if the source of data is external (xml, json, ...) then you can get your text directly from it, of course you can know this using your browser development tool. A second way that may needs some ActionScript knowledge, and if the swf is not already encrypted, is to use an **swf/flash decompiler** as [JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler](http://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/), [ActionScript Extractor](https://sites.google.com/site/as3extractor/home) or online [showmycode.com](http://www.showmycode.com/) ..., and then you can find your text, but really I don't know if that worth tiredness.